# How to split by commas that are not within parentheses?

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a string like this, where items are separated by commas but there may also be commas within items that have parenthesized content:

(EDIT: Sorry, forgot to mention that some items may not have parenthesized content)

```
"Water, Titanium Dioxide (CI 77897), Black 2 (CI 77266), Iron Oxides (CI 77491, 77492, 77499), Ultramarines (CI 77007)"
```

How can I split the string by only those commas that are NOT within parentheses? i.e:

```
["Water", "Titanium Dioxide (CI 77897)", "Black 2 (CI 77266)", "Iron Oxides (CI 77491, 77492, 77499)", "Ultramarines (CI 77007)"]
```

I think I'd have to use a regex, perhaps something like this:

```
([(]?)(.*?)([)]?)(,|$)
```

but I'm still trying to make it work.

Comment: can you show what you have attempted so far?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match all the commas  which are not inside the parenthesis. Splitting the input string according to the matched commas will give you the desired output.

```
,\s*(?![^()]*\))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pS9oV3/3)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Water, Titanium Dioxide (CI 77897), Black 2 (CI 77266), Iron Oxides (CI 77491, 77492, 77499), Ultramarines (CI 77007)"
>>> re.split(r',\s*(?![^()]*\))', s)
['Water', 'Titanium Dioxide (CI 77897)', 'Black 2 (CI 77266)', 'Iron Oxides (CI 77491, 77492, 77499)', 'Ultramarines (CI 77007)']
```

Comment: regex101.com strikes again! :) (I just commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29361673/python-re-sub-how-to-use-it#comment90091512_29361707) about it too an hour ago)

Comment: I have a similar problem but this doesn't work for me because there are inner parentheses. For example, 
"Water, Titanium Dioxide (CI 77897), Black 2 (CI 77266), Iron Oxides (CI 77491, 77492(w), 77499), Ultramarines (CI 77007)"

Comment: This doesn't work for matching parenthesis however, try this: `s="b.buildPlanPHID,coalesce(concat('D', r.Id), concat('D',c.revisionID), concat('D', d.revisionID)) as revision_id ,d.Id as diff_id"` which should break it into 3 tokens, but it creates more.

Comment: yep, this won't work on the string which contain parenthesis of level more than 1.

Comment: Was searching for a while and this is the only regex solution that worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have a simpler regexp for this:

```
rx_comma = re.compile(r",(?![^(]*\))")
result = rx_comma.split(string_to_split)
```

Explanation of the regexp:

- Match `,` that:
- Is **NOT** followed by:

  - A list of characters ending with `)`, where:
  - A list of characters between `,` and `)` does not contain `(`

It will not work in case of nested parentheses, like `a,b(c,d(e,f))`. If one needs this, a possible solution is to go through a result of split and in case of strings having an open parentheses without closing, do a merge :), like:

```
"a"
"b(c" <- no closing, merge this 
"d(e" <- no closing, merge this
"f))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it using `str.replace` and `str.split`.
You may use any character to replace `),`.

```
a = "Titanium Dioxide (CI 77897), Black 2 (CI 77266), Iron Oxides (CI 77491, 77492, 77499), Ultramarines (CI 77007)"
a = a.replace('),', ')//').split('//')
print a
```

output:-

```
['Titanium Dioxide (CI 77897)', ' Black 2 (CI 77266)', ' Iron Oxides (CI 77491, 77492, 77499)', ' Ultramarines (CI 77007)']
```

Comment: Where is the string `water` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj ohh! i just missed it in my string.

Comment: This solution does not split off items that do not end on a parenthesis (like `Water` in the example), so the string is incorrectly split.

Answer (score 0):

This version seems to work with nested parenthesis, brackets ([] or <>), and braces:

```
def split_top(string, splitter, openers="([{<", closers = ")]}>", whitespace=" \n\t"):
    ''' Splits strings at occurance of 'splitter' but only if not enclosed by brackets.
        Removes all whitespace immediately after each splitter.
        This assumes brackets, braces, and parens are properly matched - may fail otherwise '''

outlist = []
outstring = []

depth = 0

for c in string:
    if c in openers:
        depth += 1
    elif c in closers:
        depth -= 1

        if depth < 0:
            raise SyntaxError()

    if not depth and c == splitter:
        outlist.append("".join(outstring))
        outstring = []
    else:
        if len(outstring):
            outstring.append(c)
        elif c not in whitespace:
            outstring.append(c)

outlist.append("".join(outstring))

return outlist
```

Use it like this:

```
s = "Water, Titanium Dioxide (CI 77897), Black 2 (CI 77266), Iron Oxides (CI 77491, 77492, 77499), Ultramarines (CI 77007)"

split = split_top(s, ",") # splits on commas
```

It's probably not the fastest thing ever, I know.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two shorter (more elegant?) versions that will deal with nested parentheses.

A generator:

```
def split(s, sep=","):
    i = d = 0
    for j in range(len(s)):
        d += {"(": 1, ")": -1}.get(s[j], 0)
        if s[j] == sep and d == 0:
            yield s[i:j]
            i = j + 1
    yield s[i:]
```

And a more functional style one:

```
def split(s, sep=","):
    b = accumulate(s, lambda br, ch: br + {"(": 1, ")": -1}.get(ch, 0), initial=0)
    c = (ch != sep for ch in s)
    st = [i for i, x in enumerate(chain([0], starmap(int.__or__, zip(b, c)), [0])) if x == 0]
    return [s[st[i]:st[i + 1] - 1] for i in range(len(st) - 1)]
```

If you don't mind `more_itertools`, you can import `locate` from it and change the 4th line to be slightly more readable: `st = list(locate(chain([0], starmap(int.__or__, zip(b, c)), [0]), (0).__eq__))`

Answer (score -1):

Try the regex

```
[^()]*\([^()]*\),?
```

code:

```
>>x="Titanium Dioxide (CI 77897), Black 2 (CI 77266), Iron Oxides (CI 77491, 77492, 77499), Ultramarines (CI 77007)"
>> re.findall("[^()]*\([^()]*\),?",x)
['Titanium Dioxide (CI 77897),', ' Black 2 (CI 77266),', ' Iron Oxides (CI 77491, 77492, 77499),', ' Ultramarines (CI 77007)']
```

see how the regex works http://regex101.com/r/pS9oV3/1

Answer (score -1):

Using `regex`, this can be done easily with the `findall` function.

```
import re
s = "Titanium Dioxide (CI 77897), Black 2 (CI 77266), Iron Oxides (CI 77491, 77492, 77499), Ultramarines (CI 77007)"
re.findall(r"\w.*?\(.*?\)", s) # returns what you want
```

Use http://www.regexr.com/ if you want to understand regex better, and here is the link to the python documentation : https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

EDIT :
 I modified the regex string to accept content without parenthesis : `\w[^,(]*(?:\(.*?\))?`