# python re.sub how to use it

Tags: python, regex

Considering a string `django-1.8.0.dist-info`. I wish to transform it to `django==1.8.0` using `re.sub`.

I could do it using the combination of `re.search` and `.format` but I wish to know if it could be achieved with `re.sub`.

I tried this:

`re.sub(r"(?P<name>\w+)-(?P<version>[\d\.]+)", "\g<name>==\g<version>", "django-1.8.0.dist-info")` which returns `django==1.8.0.dist-info`.

I wish to take this opportunity to learn something new on regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?P<name>\w+)-(?P<version>[\d\.]+)\..*
```

Use this.Just capture the last part as well.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/23#python

Comment: Thanx for the ans. Could you help me understand the nature of re.sub? Why is it replacing the non capturing groups as well. I thought it would only replace the captured group.

Comment: @learner010 `re.sub` matches whatever you give and `replaces` only that part.So you have to match whole string if you want to replace it.You were matching partial string and then replacing so it will replace only that part

Comment: regex101.com is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is *almost* ok, but you don't want to replace - you should be using `re.match` or `re.search`

```
>>> "==".join(re.match(r"(?P<name>\w+)-(?P<version>[\d\.]+)", "django-1.8.0.dist-info").groups())
'django==1.8.0.'
```

As @Avinash pointed out - there is an extra `.` at the end

Here is one way to fix the regex (and an example of using `re.findall`):

```
>>> s = "django-1.8.0.dist-info"
>>> "==".join(*re.findall(r"(\w+)-(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)", s))
'django==1.8.0'
```

I left out the group names for (hopefully) clarity

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you really need to use regexp, but what you are after you can simply achieve as follows:

```
s="django-1.8.0.dist-info"

s=s.replace(".dist-info", "").replace('-','==')    

print(s)    # django==1.8.0
```

One regex for this could be:

```
import re
s="django-1.8.0.dist-info"
s = re.sub(r'^(\w+)-([\d\.]{5})(.+)', r'\1==\2', s)
print(s) # django==1.8.0
```

The expression make 3 groups.

- group one are characters till `-`
- group two are 5 characters (number or dot) with version number
- group three is rest

Comment: omg, why didn't I think of it, it does solves my problem but I still wish to know if its possible to achieve same result using `re.sub`. I wish to know its proper use case.

Comment: @learner010 off course you can. One possible regexp is in my amended answer.