# Retrieve part of a string from python dataframe column

Tags: python, string, pandas

I am working with a Yelp dataset which is a pandas dataframe. Each row contains information about a business and each column refers to a specific information like consumer ratings,categories, attributes, etc. I am specifically interested in extracting information from the attributes column of the dataframe. The attribute field in each row contains multiple elements and is of different lengths. I am attaching an image to make this clear. [Image of attributes column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ0II.png)

I would like to extract this information: 'RestaurantsPriceRange2: 1' from the attribute cell. Please note that the value for 'RestaurantsPriceRange2' also varies in each row and could be 1,2,3 or 4. I tried collecting each row into a list, but the length of the list varies for each row.

Can someone suggest how to pick the information that I want from the attributes column?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the attributes are also separated by commas. You could split apart each of the attributes by commas not within braces (see [How to split by commas that are not within parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633452/how-to-split-by-commas-that-are-not-within-parentheses) for a RegEx that you could use as a separator, and replace the parentheses with braces), and read the attributes and convert them into part of the dataframe as well. In this way, you could access the `Restaurant Price Range` directly.