# python splitting by 'and' and 'or', but not in parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

> (some text) or ((other text) and (some more text)) and (still more text)

I would like a python regular expression that splits it up into

```
['(some text)', '((other text) and (some more text))', '(still more text)']
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
haystack = "(some text) or ((other text) and (some more text)) and (still more text)"
re.split('(or|and)(?![^(]*.\))', haystack) # no worky
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Regex doesn't handle arbitrarily nested content very well.  Beyond the example you showed us, there could be even more layers of nested parentheses.  For this situation, using a parser might get you further than a regex.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633452/how-to-split-by-commas-that-are-not-within-parentheses

Comment: This might also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284991/parsing-nested-parentheses-in-python-grab-content-by-level

Comment: (and|or)(?![^()]*\)) doesn't work either @Christian_Dean

Comment: How about use `"(\(.+?\)) or (\(.*\)) and (\(.+?\))"` to extract content from original string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `re.findall` instead of `re.split`. And note that this would work only upto the brackets of depth 2.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '(some text) or ((other text) and (some more text)) and (still more text)'
>>> re.findall(r'\((?:\((?:\([^()]*\)|[^()]*)*\)|[^()])*\)', s)
['(some text)', '((other text) and (some more text))', '(still more text)']
>>>
```

Comment: I tried to simplify my string and it backfired. Your solution does not work for my real string...
(substringof('needle',name)) or ((role eq 'needle') and (substringof('needle',email))) or (job eq 'needle') or (office eq 'needle')

Comment: @user1571934 how about this https://regex101.com/r/zDmF3s/1 ? If the depth goes further long then drop the idea of using regex. Write your own parser.

Answer (score 3):

This solution works for arbitrarily nested parentheses, which a regex couldn't (`s` is the original string):

```
from pyparsing import nestedExpr
def lst_to_parens(elt):
    if isinstance(elt,list):
        return '(' + ' '.join(lst_to_parens(e) for e in elt) + ')'
    else:
        return elt

split = nestedExpr('(',')').parseString('(' + s + ')').asList()
split_lists = [elt for elt in split[0] if isinstance(elt,list)]
print ([lst_to_parens(elt) for elt in split_lists])
```

Output:

```
['(some text)', '((other text) and (some more text))', '(still more text)']
```

For OP's real test case:

```
s = "(substringof('needle',name)) or ((role eq 'needle') and (substringof('needle',email))) or (job eq 'needle') or (office eq 'needle')"
```

Output:

```
["(substringof ('needle' ,name))", "((role eq 'needle') and (substringof ('needle' ,email)))", "(job eq 'needle')", "(office eq 'needle')"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also check this

```
import re
s = '(some text) or ((other text) and (some more text)) and (still more text)'
find_string = re.findall(r'[(]{2}[a-z\s()]*[)]{2}|[(][a-z\s]*[)]', s)
print(find_string)
```

output:

```
['(some text)', '((other text) and (some more text))', '(still more text)']
```

**Edit**

```
find_string = re.findall(r'[(\s]{2}[a-z\s()]*[)\s]{2}|[(][a-z\s]*[)]', s)
```

Comment: this is not the right way of matching the brackets.. what if there any text present between two open brackets?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, will you please give a sample string? Thanks.

Comment: check your regex with this `'(some text) or ( (other text) and (some more text)) and (still more text)'` string..

Comment: yes got it. is `r'[(\s]{2}[a-z\s()]*[)\s]{2}|[(][a-z\s]*[)]'` okey?  I get the output right for this regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
    re.split('[a-f]+', '0a3B9', flags=re.IGNORECASE)