# String split using regex with pattern present in text

Tags: python, regex, token

I have many string that I need to split by commas. Example:

```
myString = r'test,Test,NEAR(this,that,DISTANCE=4),test again,"another test"'
myString = r'test,Test,FOLLOWEDBY(this,that,DISTANCE=4),test again,"another test"'
```

My desired output would be:

```
["test", "Test", "NEAR(this,that,DISTANCE=4)", "test again", """another test"""] #list length = 5
```

I can't figure out how to keep the commas between "this,that,DISTANCE" in one item. I tried this:

```
l = re.compile(r',').split(myString) # matches all commas
l = re.compile(r'(?<!\(),(?=\))').split(myString) # (negative lookback/lookforward) - no matches at all
```

Any ideas? Let's say the list of allowed "functions" is defined as:

```
f = ["NEAR","FOLLOWEDBY","AND","OR","MAX"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split by commas that are not within parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633452/how-to-split-by-commas-that-are-not-within-parentheses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\([^()]*\)|[^,])+
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OMSqbI/1/).

The `(?:\([^()]*\)|[^,])+` pattern matches one or more occurrences of any substring between parentheses with no `(` and `)` in them or any char other than `,`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/NOiFuJ):

```
import re
rx = r"(?:\([^()]*\)|[^,])+"
s = 'test,Test,NEAR(this,that,DISTANCE=4),test again,"another test"'
print(re.findall(rx, s))
# => ['test', 'Test', 'NEAR(this,that,DISTANCE=4)', 'test again', '"another test"']
```

Answer (score 0):

If explicitly want to specify which strings count as functions, you need to build the regex dynamically. Otherwise, go with Wiktor's solution.

```
>>> functions = ["NEAR","FOLLOWEDBY","AND","OR","MAX"]
>>> funcs = '|'.join('{}\([^\)]+\)'.format(f) for f in functions)
>>> regex = '({})|,'.format(funcs)
>>>
>>> myString1 = 'test,Test,NEAR(this,that,DISTANCE=4),test again,"another test"'
>>> list(filter(None, re.split(regex, myString1)))
['test', 'Test', 'NEAR(this,that,DISTANCE=4)', 'test again', '"another test"']
>>> myString2 = 'test,Test,FOLLOWEDBY(this,that,DISTANCE=4),test again,"another test"'
>>> list(filter(None, re.split(regex, myString2)))
['test',
 'Test',
 'FOLLOWEDBY(this,that,DISTANCE=4)',
 'test again',
 '"another test"']
```