# split by comma if comma not in between brackets while allowing characters to be outside the brackets with in the same comma split

Tags: python, regex

I have this python script. That uses some regular expression.
I want to split the string s, but commas while ignoring any commas that exists within the brackets.

```
s = """aa,bb,(cc,dd),m(ee,ff)"""
splits = re.split(r'\s*(\([^)]*\)|[^,]+)', s, re.M|re.S)
print('\n'.join(splits))
Actual output:
    aa
    ,
    bb
    ,
    (cc,dd)
    ,
    m(ee
    ,
    ff)
Desired output: 
    aa
    bb
    (cc,dd)
    m(ee,ff)
```

So I can't make it handle having text outside the brackets.
Was hoping someone could help me out.

Comment: I changed the word 'expected' to 'desired'

Comment: How are you getting `m(ee,ff)`?

Comment: I'm not, that's what I want. It's outputting 
m(ee\n
,\n
ff)\n
instead.

Comment: No, but there is no `m(ee,ff)` in the original string

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake I made while editting. Fixed it now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split by commas that are not within parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633452/how-to-split-by-commas-that-are-not-within-parentheses)

Comment: I originally wanted to consider both, but then decided to just do brackets to make it siimpler.

Comment: I looked at that one and it doesn't work for keeping the stuff outside the brackets in the same split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with a lookahead for split:

```
>>> s = """aa,bb,(cc,dd),m(ee,ff)"""
>>> print ( re.split(r',(?![^()]*\))', s) )
['aa', 'bb', '(cc,dd)', 'm(ee,ff)']
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UXdHRe/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `,`: Match a comma
- `(?![^()]*\))`: A negative lookahead assertion that makes sure we don't match comma inside `(...)` by asserting that there is no `)` ahead after 0 or more not bracket characters.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `findall` instead - repeat a group that matches `(`s followed by non-`)` characters, followed by `)`, or matches non-`,` characters:

```
s = """aa,bb,m(cc,dd)"""
matches = re.findall(r'(?:\([^(]+\)|[^,])+', s, re.M|re.S)
print('\n'.join(matches))
```

If speed is an issue, you can make it a bit more efficient by putting `(` in the other negative character set, and alternating it first:

```
(?:[^(,]+|\([^(]+\))+
```

Comment: Check no of steps it takes on https://regex101.com/r/UXdHRe/2 (272 steps) vs my suggested split regex  (146 steps).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar, but I also had nested brackets.
The proposed regex expressions do NOT handle nesting.

I couldn't find a regex solution, but here is a python function solution that achieves the same thing:

```
def comma_split(text: str) -> list[str]:
    flag = 0
    buffer = ""
    result = []
    for char_ in text:
        if char_ == "[":
            flag += 1
        elif char_ == "]":
            flag -= 1
        elif char_ == "," and flag == 0:
            result.append(buffer)
            buffer = ""
            continue
        buffer += char_
    if buffer:
        result.append(buffer)
    return result
```

Answer (score -1):

try : r',*([^,()]*[(][^()]*[)][^,]*)|([^,]+)'

tested on regex101 : https://regex101.com/r/pJxRwQ/1